# Filtar Aniversariantes do dia

Tags: mysql

Estou querendo filtrar os aniversariantes do dia, mas não estou conseguindo.
Só consigo se coloco exatamente a data de nascimento; para dar certo precisava filtrar as datas de nascimento do mesmo dia e mês (descartando o ano de nascimento)

```
SELECT NomeCompleto, Telefone FROM tblcliente WHERE DataNascimento = '1995-12-08'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT NomeCompleto, Telefone FROM tblcliente WHERE MONTH(DataNascimento) = 5
```

Neste caso, usando `MONTH`, podemos filtrar por mês. 
Da mesma forma, podemos então fazer usando `YEAR`, para filtrar por ano, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
SELECT NomeCompleto, Telefone FROM tblcliente WHERE YEAR(DataNascimento) = '2017'
```

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, para obter o resultado esperado:

```
SELECT NomeCompleto, Telefone FROM tblcliente WHERE DAY(DataNascimento) = '02' AND MONTH(DataNascimento) = '5'
```

Para efeitos de pesquisa e conhecimento, você também pode filtrar por período, em caso de relatórios, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT NomeCompleto, Telefone FROM tblcliente WHERE DataNascimento BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra opção seria a seguinte:

```
SELECT data FROM public.estoque where extract (month from data) = extract (month from CURRENT_DATE) and  extract (day from data) = extract (day from CURRENT_DATE)
```

Onde você extrai o mês e dia da sua tabela e compara com a data atual, assim retornando apenas as com o mesmo dia e mês independente do ano.

**Observação:** Fiz em postgresql essa query mas é tranquilo para alterar para mysql

[Aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_extract.asp) mostra como utilizar o `extract` em MySQL

No seu caso acredite que fique algo semelhante a isso:

```
SELECT NomeCompleto, Telefone FROM tblcliente WHERE extract(month from DataNascimento) = extract(month from NOW()) and extract(day from DataNascimento) = extract(day from NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode buscar todos os registros que forem de um determinado dia usando a função [DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day)  e mês usando a função [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM tblcliente 
WHERE MONTH(DataNascimento) = 12 AND DAY(DataNascimento) = 8
```

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo funcionando online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa2d27/1)

Uma outra forma de fazer a pesquisa é buscar todos os registros de uma determinada data independente de sua hora, utilizando [Date_Add()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblcliente 
WHERE DataNascimento >= '1993/08/04'
AND DataNascimento < Date_Add('1993/08/04',INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo funcionando online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ca835/6)